# Which resource to learn Rhino Mocking frameworks?

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm very new at mocking and Rhino Mock. I searched for resources about learning Rhino Mocks but not found an easy one. Does anyone knows any good resources to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try these screen casts

http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/Rhino%20Mocks

http://www.ayende.com/hibernating-rhinos.aspx

Blog entries from the Author himself

http://ayende.com/Blog/category/487.aspx

Comment: I myself add StackOverflow related questions

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the [Wiki](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx)?

Comment: I tried some pages of that wiki. Some sections seems out-of-dated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this quick reference guide](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/GetFile.aspx?File=Rhino+Mocks+3.3+Quick+Reference.pdf) to be extremely helpful in day-to-day development using Rhino Mocks. A printout of it sits on my desk and is never far from the top of the pile.